Impact of $U(1)$ gauge symmetry violation on quantum theories of Gravity?
QED and QFT take $U(1)$ gauge symmetry as fundamental and obtain extremely successful predictions at the scales and experiments physicists have been able to perform. This should not be taken lightly.
However, is not clear to me that there exists good arguments or reasons to believe electromagnetic gauge invariance will be respected by gravitational interactions. If for example, a subtle choice of gauge is preferred by gravitational physics, I don't think current astrophysical observational data could detect it or rule it out.
Additionally, I haven't ever seen a good theoretical argument on that regard, besides Occam razor's heuristic arguments.
Question: Under the best known approaches to quantize gravity, how essential is the $U(1)$ symmetry assumption to the theory? If the assumption is removed, would the theories have to be heavily modified or reformulated? or is that assumption simply not necessary to begin with?

I am a bit confused about the question. Why do you think gravity may imply in some preferred gauge choice for QED?


The standard classical combination of EM and GR definitely respects the gauge symmetry. I don't understand why you would specifically suspect it to be violated by quantum gravity. 2. Do you understand what removing ("breaking" is the wrong term as it is protected by Elitzur's theorem) the gauge symmetry means in the classical and QED theories? I'm not sure why you'd jump to quantum gravity as a starting point to understand the role of the U(1) symmetry.


Breaking a gauge symmetry is never something you should break this is true in a setting with or without gr. Normally when we treat a theory of Quantum gravity  with charged particles all the interactions just respect the gauge symmetry.  Think of how you would go from a Lagrangian in flat space to one in curved space. As $g$ is not charged under the gauged U(1) all interactions still satisfy the gauge constraint.

@Gold I have no reason at all to believe it, I am arguing there that as far as I know, there would be no observational constraint on it.

@ACuriousMind 1. Observational GR does not seem to constrain it either way, am I under the wrong impression here? The main arguments would be that it is so because theory as it exists relies on it or demands it

I think breaking might not be the best term, I am referring to symmetries being fulfilled well enough in certain regimes while not being exact. Isospin invariance in nuclear interactions would be a good example


@ThomasTappeiner I think my reply above also addresses your comment

I think there is a slight difference. There is no such thing as a gauge symmetry being partially fulfilled. You would not think of a Guage theory as a physical symmetry but rather a mathematical tool. The gauge redundancy by Definition is not physical as it is an exicit over counting of degrees of freedom (at least that's what most definitions of gauge theory assume).

Breaking such a gauge symmetry is essentially saying that a non physical redundancy becomes physical.

I wonder, when you say “$U(1)$ gauge symmetry violation” do you mean charge non-conservation in QG or are you asking what happens to gauge symmetries in QG theories without the usual underlying smooth spacetime?
